# JS doesn't work on Firefox and Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a problem with my code.
Why on firefox and Internet Explore doesn't work?
This code work very well on Google Chrome.

JS:

```
    var i=1;

function dragStart(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='move';
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
  ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target,50,50);
  return true;
}

// these functions prevents default behavior of browser
function dragEnter(ev) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return true;
}
function dragOver(ev) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

// function defined for when drop element on target
function dragDrop(ev) {

  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
   if (ev.shiftKey)
  {

    var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
    nodeCopy.id = "newId"+i; /* We cannot use the same ID */
    ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
    i++;

  }
  else
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

  ev.stopPropagation();
  return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <article id="dropIt" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" ondrop="return dragDrop(event)" ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></article>

<article id="holder" class="no-print" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" ondrop="return dragDrop(event)" ondragover="return dragOver(event)">
<div class="drag" id="boxB" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)"></div>
</article>
```

Why on firefox and Internet Explore doesn't work?
Thanks

Comment: I do not see anything also in chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/jqtubdgp/

Comment: Replace all `ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"` to `ondragenter="dragEnter"`

Comment: Can you give us more info; like what doesnt work, what were you trying to do.

Comment: Do you have *any* more information besides "doesn't work"?! Have you had a look at  the respective Javascript consoles to look at any error output?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yLxu8ahc/1/ i want drag and drop pink boxs on blue box. This code work very well on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the event properly like this

```
// these functions prevents default behavior of browser
function dragEnter(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return true;
}
function dragOver(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: This will fix Firefox but not Internet Explorer
See https://github.com/MihaiValentin/setDragImage-IE for ie

Comment: Good ... Thanks you (i change ev with event)